# NSDatePicker - getting the value when it is changed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdatepicker

How would I get notified of a value of a NSDatePicker, when it's changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've only done it on the iPhone with UIDatePicker but it is similar on the Mac, you register as a delegate and receive messages. See [Apple's Docs here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSDatePickerCellDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSDatePickerCellDelegate).

I should clarify, this tells you when it changed, you still need to call `-dateValue` to get the date.

Answer (score 4):

The same you would any other control. Options are:

- Target/Action
- Binding
- Observe notification
- Delegate

Comment: AS of 2016, NSDatePicker doesn't seem to send an action or run KVO (although the problem with the latter may be a bug in my code)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the picker's `value` binding to a property of your controller, or a property of a model object (through a controller).